# Handle Can Execute Conditions in dynamic button c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Button as accessory in my TabControl where 2 TabItem resides. This button copies the different object used in the tabs. I want to be able to implement a different functionality to that Copy Button for each tab, in one command, so I implemented a general Copy Command in the main View that checks the current tab index to see we're currently in what tab, but now what is the best way to I handle my cannot execute conditions without repeating my switch case in the Conditions methode? For example, the first tab button cannot be execute if its object is null, the tab button cannot be executed when its object is null, etc.

```
public RelayCommandWithCannotExecuteReason Copy
    {
        get
        {
            if (_copy == null)
            {
                _copy = new RelayCommandWithCannotExecuteReason(
                    x =>
                    {

                        switch (SelectedTabIndex) {
                            case 1:
                                Clipboard.SetData("First", object1);
                                break;
                            case 2:

                                Clipboard.SetData("Second", object2;
                                break;
                        }

                    }, CanCopyConditions);
            }

            return _copy;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invest time in MvvM, this way you would have had ViewModels for each TabItem, then each of those ViewModels would determine if you could use the button. It seriously saves you time in the long run. I know it is a pain to set up and there is a lot of boiler plate code but it's worth it.

Comment: @XAMlMAX and after setting it up, how can i accomplish this feature that i want?

Comment: I already told you. Each item would have it's own `ViewModel` then each `TabItem` would be determined by the `TabControl` using `DataTemplate` I think (it might be a `ControlTemplate`, it's been a while). In that template you would have a button that each VM would implement and then decide whether you can execute it or even see it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not a Binding problem or a WPF problem. It's a design-pattern question.

### Solution

Define a `List` or a `Dictionary` to store your objects of all tabs, and then you can fetch each object using an index instead of the duplicated switch case.

For example, you can define a `Dictionary` with a `TabIndex` key and the associated object.

```
private Dictionary<int, (string name, object value)> _tabObjectDictionary = new Dictionary<int, (string, object)>
{
    { 1, ("First", object1) },
    { 2, ("Second", object2) },
    { 3, ("Third", object3) },
};
```

Or you can just infer the index with a single `List` index.

```
private List<(string name, object value)> _tabObjectList = new List<(string, object)>
{
    ("First", object1),
    ("Second", object2),
    ("Third", object3),
};
```

Then you can get the object by using the index.

```
public RelayCommandWithCannotExecuteReason Copy
{
    get
    {
        if (_copy == null)
        {
            _copy = new RelayCommandWithCannotExecuteReason(
                x =>
                {
                    var (name, value) = _tabObjectDictionary[SelectedTabIndex];
                    Clipboard.SetData(name, value);

                }, x =>
                {
                    var (name, value) = _tabObjectDictionary[SelectedTabIndex];
                    // Verify your conditions here.
                    return value != null;
                });
        }

        return _copy;
    }
}
```

Tips: You may have to install a NuGet package named [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/)